# Unable to pass php variable to html using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

The following is my controller Wordings_test.php code

The issue is I am not able to print @wording.product. Even though, I can print @wording.template_name.
Thanks

```
  class Wordings_test extends Controller{
    function show($f3)
    {
        $wordings = Wordings::all()->orderBy('id')->select()->toArray();

        foreach ($wordings as $wording) {
        $wording['product'] = ProductTypes::where(['id' => 
        $wording['product_type_id']])->select()->getAttribute('name');

        }
        $f3->set('wordings',$wordings);
        $this->render('admin/wordings/view')
    }
```

The following is the template code view.html

```
<a href="/admin/brokerage-headgroups/add" class="btn btn-success pull-right showLoader"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add New Brokerage Head Group</a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="brokerageheadlist" class="active in tab-pane fade">
                    <table class="table table-bordered adminTable" id="brokerageheadList">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Wording</th>
                            <th>Product Type</th>
                            <th style="width:140px;">Controls</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <repeat group="{{ @wordings }}"  value="{{ @wording }}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ @wording.template_name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ @wording.product }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info showLoader" href="/admin/wordings/edit-wordings/{{ @wording.id }}">Edit</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{@brokeragehead.id}}">Delete</button>
                                <div id="myModal{{@brokeragehead.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
```

Comment: Are you sure `$wording['product']` is not null ? You can't display it okay, but what happend ? Error ? Nothing appear ? Btw the code look like really strange for laravel, which version ?

Comment: I can echo wording ('product') in php but not in HTML

Comment: I don't know the version of laravel

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine I can echo wording ('product') in php but not in HTML. Don't know the laravel version

Comment: so other than your array everything is printed on the page?

Comment: @DsRaj it prints in php but doesn't pass to html

Comment: Moreover @wording.template_name works perfectly